# Brute force algorithm for "Binary Puzzle"

Tags: algorithms

### Binary puzzle

Binary puzzle is an puzzle played on a $n × n$ grid; intially some of the cells contain a zero or a one (fixed cells); the aim of the game is to fill the remaining empty cells according to the following rules:

- Each cell should contain a zero or a one.
- No more than two similar numbers next to or below each other are allowed.
- Each row and each column should contain an equal number of zeros and ones.
- Each row is unique and each column is unique.

---

**Decision problem:**

> **Input :** A partially filled n×n grid with 0's and 1's.
>
> **Question :** Can we fill the
>   empty cells with a zero or a one in a way that follow the above mention rules ?

For $n \times n $ this problem known to be [NP-complete](http://www.nearly42.org/vdisk/cstheory/binaryp.pdf).

**Brute force Algorithm :**

1. If the given $n \times n$ is empty then it is an yes instance ( use the basis set of $ \mathcal{ R^{n\times n}}$).
2. Case I: If only one row is filled and it is an valid row  (follow the above mentions rules ) then it is an yes instance. Second row is going to be the complement of first row (make 0 to 1 and 1 to 0).
3. Case II : if $k$ rows are filled and they are valid then I can fill the table upto 2k rows by using trick of complement.

**Question** :  How to design a brute force algorithm for the problem stated above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k$ fixed cells, you try all $2^{n^2-k}$ possibilities of filling the remaining $n^2-k$ cells and check for each fully filled board whether it fulfills all stated constraints.